# Animation in SVG using svg-edit

Tags: animation, svg, image-editing, svg-animate

I'm using svg-edit.googlecode.com. Is it possible to make animation in SVG? i need to animate an Image in a game which will be rotating its head. I have 10 frames of images for animation, but I dont know how to bring it into svg for Animation.
Need Help to make my Game Character to Animate by SVG.

```
<svg width="512" height="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
<g>
<title>Layer 1</title>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVG & Spritesheets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414207/svg-spritesheets); see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418128/using-a-clipping-path-with-a-positioned-object-in-webkit